# How to load css after require_tree .?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to do this?

*../application.css*

```
*= require_tree .
*= require after_tree.css
```

All my .css files in the same directory.
I want to load after_tree.css to be able to rewrite the rules that was loaded in others .css by require_tree .

Comment: You need to explicitly require the files to maintain the order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to require_self

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

`*= require_self` inserts the content of the file itself (after the directives). This is often useful when you want to make sure that JavaScript code from a manifest comes before any other code that is loaded with require_tree. We see an example of that in the default application.css.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to not use require_tree, but load them all individually if you want to control the order.

You could put all the files whose order you don't care about in a subdir, then `require_tree ./subdir` instead of `require_tree`. The require any files you do care about the order of after that.

Answer (score 0):

To **maintain the order** you need to **explicitly require** like this:

```
*= bootstrap.css
*= override_bootstrap.css
*= my_style.css
*= require_tree .
```